# PHP: save 2d Array in Database without JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, normalization

I send this values to a PHP script which saves the rowData Value to a database.
This are the POST Parameters:

```
amount  1
ident   1
orderID 101447
rowData [["0","","","","",""],["0","","","","",""],["0","","","","",""]]
storage 2
```

now I need a way to format a 2D Array in PHP to the same format like the rowData Parameter.
Does anybody have some tips or a hint for me?

This is my JS Code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1/some/dir/file.php",
            data: {
                orderID: orderID,
                storage:storage,
                ident:ident,
                amount:amount,
                rowData:rowData//this is the 2D Array
            }
```

Comment: Is the data passed in json format?

Comment: why not json ?  this looks like JSON so : json_decode('[["0","","","","",""],["0","","","","",""],["0","","","","",""]]'); will work.

Comment: i send a 2D array to the php script without any convertation. i updated my question with the ajax code

Comment: khazul the decode will work, but if i use json_encode i got some {} at the start/end wich will break my script. normally json would be the best way, but at the moment i doesnt have the possibilities to change the complete procedure

Comment: [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)?

Comment: _“but if i use json_encode i got some {} at the start/end”_ - then you did not feed the proper data structure to it … If you get {} somewhere, then your data type was an _object_, whereas you apparently wanted an _array_.

Comment: if I were you I'd surely go with json_encode/decode as it's quite simple and readable. maybe serialize would work too. But, in my opinion, you shouldn't store data like that unless you're 100% sure you won't do any operations with them (like counting stats, etc.) as it's too costly and sometimes even impossible.

Answer (score 0):

with json you can do op with data, with serialize code will get complex;

other way can be `fopen()` AND   `readfile()` OR create XML elements with serial numbers